# How to pass variables while calling a function in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to create a rest api using codeIgniter. I have a method which gives a json object from android (client).

**Below is the function in my controller**

```
 function addUser_post(){
    $username = $this->post('username');
    $password = $this->post('password');
    echo $username;
    echo $password;
    $this->load->model('register_model');
    $data =  $this->register_model->addUser($username,$password);

    $this->response($data,200);
}
```

**Below is my function in model class**

```
function addUser($username, $password){

    $uname = $username;
    $passwo = $password;

    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'span123','naveendb');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usertable(username,password) VALUES('$uname','$passwo')";

  if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
      return "user not added to the database";
  }else{
      return "user added";
  }
}
```

I am not able to understand where is have went wrong. I am a newbie to CodeIgniter and i have good knowledge of java.

I want to learn this.

Please help

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using  CodeIgniter REST server library?

Comment: Yes https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/tree/master/application

Comment: You dint explain... what exactly is the problem

Comment: I want to pass the variable from controller to a function in model

Comment: is the `echo $username;` and  `echo $password;` showing what you are posting?

Comment: Yes its showing... @GopakumarGopalan

Comment: then you are doing it correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use codeigniter db library. Set the database credentials in `application/config/database.php`. Please reffer :[Database Configuration](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html).

```
function addUser($username, $password){
  //If database class is not autoloaded then add the line below
  $this->load->database();

  $uname = $username;
  $passwo = $password;

  $data = array(
    'username' => $uname ,
    'password' => $passwo 
  );

  if(!$this->db->insert('usertable', $data)){
    return "user not added to the database";
  }else{
    return "user added";
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.